# Radio buttons used in while statement from query

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I am working on a survey.  I have a database of questions with possible responses.  I created a query that displays all questions and choices.  Everything displays fine.  Problem is I can only select radio button for one question.  Here is the section of code:

```
echo' <form method="post" action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'">';
                            echo '<p class="hwhite">Please answer every question:</p><table>';
                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survey_question
                            WHERE formNum = 3"); 
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            Echo'<tr><td class=reg>' . $row['question'] . '</td><td class=tdleft>';
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='qId[]' value=" .$row['qId'] .">";
                            //echo "<input type='text' name='response[]' > this is the test one";
                            Echo "<input type='radio' name='response[]' value='1'>" .$row['r1']." <br>";
                            Echo"<input type='radio' name='response[]' value='2' />" .$row['r2']." <br>";
                            Echo'<input type="radio" name="response[]" value="3" />' .$row['r3'].' <br>';
                            Echo'<input type="radio" name="response[]" value="4" /> ' .$row['r4'].'<br>';
                            echo"</td></tr>";
                            }
                            echo"</table></div>";
                            echo'<input type="hidden" name="complete" value="complete">';
                            echo'<input type="hidden" name="person" value="person">';
                            echo'<input type="reset" value="Reset Form" /></p>';
                            echo'<input type="submit" value="Complete Survey" class="button" alt="Submit form" border="0"/>';
                            echo'<br> </form><br>';
```

Do you mean this: 
     Please answer every question:

Which of the following illnesses should a food handler report to manager.Headache 
Sore throat 
Swollen knee 
 Mild Diarrhea 
Which chicken breast is cooked correctlycooked to internal temperature of 157°F 
cooked to surface temperature of 165° F 
cooked to internal temperature of 168°F 
 cooked to surface temperature of 155°F

*** Update

```
// find out how many records there are to update 
                        $size = count($_POST['qId']); 
                        // start a loop in order to update each record 
                        $i = 0; 

                        while ($i < $size) { 
                            // define each variable 

                            $qId =  $_POST['qId'][$i]; 
                            $rNum =  $_POST['response'][$i]; 
                        // do the update 
                            $query = "INSERT survey_results (qId, rNum) Value ('$qId', '$rNum')"; 
                        mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
                        ++$i;
```

Comment: the problem may lie in the php itself (code you didn't include), if you're not using a `foreach`, and/or treating it as an array to allow multiple choices.

Comment: run your php script and show us your source code in html, please

Comment: "Problem is I can only select radio button for one question"  How many options did you expect radio buttons to select? your radio buttons are all of the same group, how about you use checkboxes instead?

Comment: *"Problem is I can only select radio button for one question."* - Duh, scratch my first comment; use checkboxes for this. It just dinged on me now *lol* However, I stand to be "somewhat right" about it (my first comment, which I kept intact). If changing them to checkboxes doesn't fix this, then the problem is also elsewhere.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean.  I edited question with the code from my screen, the website is www.marylandfoodhandler.com/surveyForm.php

Comment: [Reload my comment (click) here, I edited it...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245524/radio-buttons-used-in-while-statement-from-query#comment67753575_40245524) - and visiting your website won't do us much good. All we'll see is rendered/parsed PHP/mysql. Post your full php/mysql for this.

Comment: Fred, I only want one option per question, however, I am looping through multiple questions then writing to a database.

Comment: then you'll need to rethink this. Radios of the same group name can only use one value, unlike checkboxes.

Comment: I am at a loss for how to accomplish this.  Surely I am not the first one to do a survey / quiz in this manner.  When I comment out the radio boxes and change it to only a text box response it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of the radio buttons for each question. Right now they are all named response[]. I would probably add the question ID to the button names. Something like:

```
Echo "<input type='radio' name='response_" . $row['qId'] . "[]' value='1'>" .$row['r1']." <br>";
```

Comment: made this edit.  Can now select one option per question.  However it is not updating to database correctly   Echo'<input type="radio" name="response[' . $row['qId'] . ']" value="3" />' .$row['r3'].' <br>';

Comment: // find out how many records there are to update 
      $size = count($_POST['qId']); 
      // start a loop in order to update each record 
      $i = 0; 

      while ($i < $size) { 
       // define each variable 
       
       $qId =  $_POST['qId'][$i]; 
       $rNum =  $_POST['response'][$i]; 
      // do the update 
       $query = "INSERT survey_results (qId, rNum) Value ('$qId', '$rNum')"; 
      mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
      ++$i;

Comment: `$rNum = $_POST['response_'.$i][$i];`

Comment: received this response: Undefined index: response0 in /hsphere/local/home/smlwfarace/marylandfoodhandler.com/surveyForm.php on line 72 Notice: Undefined index: response1 in /hsphere/local/home/smlwfarace/marylandfoodhandler.com/surveyForm.php on line 72 Warning:  I did not include the _ in either place. But that shouldn't matter

Comment: Sorry. That first `$i` should be `$_POST['qId'][$i]`

Comment: that is the same variable for $qId ?  I need the value of the response. either 1, 2,3 or 4

Comment: The keys in the `$_POST` array will have the same names that are used in the HTML. So if the first question has an id of 1, your radio buttons for that question are named "response1" or "response1[]". When you submit the form, `$_POST['response1']` will contain the answer to the first question. Looking at it longer this time, I don't think you need the `[$i]` when getting the answers. `$_POST['response'.$qId]` should be the answer for a question.

Comment: I tried $rNum = $_POST['response'.$qId][$i] ; and get error  Notice: Undefined index: response12 in /hsphere/local/home/smlwfarace/marylandfoodhandler.com/surveyForm.php on line 72 Notice: Undefined index: response13 in /hsphere/local/home/smlwfarace/marylandfoodhandler.com/surveyForm.php on line 72

Comment: I would do `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of the page. It will show you all of the stuff in the $_POST array. Should give you a better idea of how to get the answers out of it.

Comment: $rNum = $_POST['response'][$qId] ;  seems to be working!!  Thank you all this one had me stumped as a self taught php'er